# Extra points on "faces" in edit

Tags: edit-mode

I just loaded latest build of 2.8. In edit, face view, I have sixteen reference points in each face. Is this a setting I have off with this clean load or is it a bug?
[image]

Comment: If you turn on subdivision surface modifier visible in edit mode it looks like this.

Comment: You can turn off the face center dot in view port overlay option if needed. And that might be submod edit visible to act like the picture shows.